# Проблемы линковки в Code::Blocks (undefined reference to)

Tags: c++11, codeblocks

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, проект в Visual Studio компилится, а в Code Blocks

> undefined reference to `sw(int&, int&)

Подскажите, нет ли ошибки в коде или проблема в какой-то особенности о которой я не знаю?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Func.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    a = 5;
    b = 10;
    sw(a,b);
    cout << a << " " << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Func.hpp

```
#ifndef FUNC_HPP_INCLUDED
#define FUNC_HPP_INCLUDED
void sw(int& a, int& b);
void sw(int* a, int* b); 
#endif // FUNC_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Func.cpp

```
#include "Func.hpp"
void sw(int& a, int& b)
{
    int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
};

void sw(int* a, int* b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
};
```

Comment: Вы точно объяснили в проекте, что у вас несколько линкуемых файлов? Ощущение, что линковщик не знает, что должен линковать `func.obj`.

Comment: @Harry
На тех ресурсах, где я учился, говорилось о том, что линковщик сам ищет определения по всем cpp проекта. Если линкуемые файлы нужно задавать, то как?

Comment: А проект *включает* второй файл?

Comment: @Harry
Да, включает.
Ubuntu 16.04, GCC компилятор

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. 
Оказалось, что при добавлении файла, я чекал, только "Add file to active project"
А надо было еще "In build target : Debug, Release", что позволяет компилятору работать с данным файлом в Debug и Release соответственно